# How should I define a superclass that guarantees a property that is readable but not writable?

Tags: matlab, inheritance, properties, attributes, abstract-class

I want to define a data structure that can be used as an input for various methods that access the data in a read-only fashion, but in various contexts this data should either be completely mutable, or strictly read-only because it will store other data that describes how the data was assembled in that particular instance.

In theory, this problem seems like it should be demonstrable as a minimal example with an abstract superclass and two different subclasses:

```
classdef (Abstract) Super
    properties (Abstract)
        Prop
    end

    methods
        function DoSomething(obj)
            doSomethingElse(obj.Prop);
        end
    end
end

classdef MutableSub < Super
    properties
        Prop
    end
end

classdef ImmutableSub < Super
    properties (SetAccess = protected)
        Prop
    end

    methods
        function obj = ImmutableSub(value)
            obj.Prop = value;
        end
    end
end
```

This doesn't work, however. Attempting to construct an instance of `ImmutableSub`, e.g. `ImmutableSub(someData)`, produces the error:

> The definition of property '`Prop`' in class '`ImmutableSub`' differs from its definition in the superclass
> '`Super`'. This is caused by either conflicting access permissions or differing values of the Constant attribute.

I could make this error go away by removing the `SetAccess` attribute within `ImmutableSub` – but this will make that class more fragile because its instances will not be properly protected from property changes so any inadvertent modification will be harder to detect.

I could instead make the error go away by removing the abstract property definition from `Super` and just rely on all subclasses taking care to define a property `Prop` that doesn't restrict `GetAccess`. But if a subclass fails to do this then nothing will break until attempting to call a method like `DoSomething`, at which point it may be unclear why it's supposed to work.

Essentially I'd like to retain the benefits of explicitly defining these aspects of the data structure that make `Abstract` and `SetAccess` property attributes useful features of MATLAB class definitions, without committing the offence that MATLAB seems to take at using them in this particular combination. What is the "right" way to do this?

Comment: This would violate the Liskov Substitution Principle - i.e. you cannot use `ImmutableSub` as you can a `Super`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle . (If you still want to do this, you could make the property `Dependent` and throw a runtime error in `ImmutableSub` in an overloaded method hooked up to the property).

Comment: @Edric thanks for the useful reference; I guess my conceptualisation of the problem is not that `ImmutableSub` takes away the `set` capability but that `MutableSub` adds it. MATLAB doesn't permit this by the overriding of access attributes or by overloading/subclassing the `set` method, but the LSP provides a good reason why a special subclass public method for assigning the property is perhaps not as smelly as I felt it would be.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, there are some subclass properties which must be aligned. One workaround is to use a dependent property for the main value of `Prop`, and another protected property which dictates a class's mutability, defaulting to `false` in the superclass according to your desired behaviour.

Then we can use a custom setter `set.Prop` which checks the object's mutability property and either errors or assigns the value to a protected `Prop_` property. This pairs with a custom getter `get.Prop` which simply retrieves the value of the protected `obj.Prop_`. As shown below:

Superclass:

```
classdef (Abstract) Super
    properties (Dependent)
        Prop
    end
    properties (Access = protected)
        Mutable = false
        Prop_
    end

    methods
        function DoSomething(obj)
            doSomethingElse(obj.Prop);
        end
        function obj = set.Prop(obj, p)
            if obj.Mutable
                obj.Prop_ = p;
            else
                error( 'Prop is immutable' );
            end
        end
        function p = get.Prop(obj)
            p = obj.Prop_;
        end
    end
    methods (Access = protected)
        function obj = setProp(obj, p)
        end
    end
end
```

Subclasses:

```
classdef MutableSub < Super    
    methods
        function obj = MutableSub()
            obj.Mutable = true;
        end
    end
end

classdef ImmutableSub < Super
    methods
        function obj = ImmutableSub(value)
            obj.Prop_ = value;
        end
    end
end
```

Note the slight drawback within the `ImmutableSub` where we have to assign to the protected property `obj.Prop_` directly within the constructor, otherwise you'd trip the error in `set.Prop` because the object is immutable. An alternative here would be setting `obj.Mutable = true` at the start of the constructor and `obj.Mutable = false` at the end of the constructor, or some other flag which is only used within the constructor.

Result:

```
>> p = MutableSub()
p = 
  MutableSub with properties:
    Prop: []

>> p.Prop = 1
p = 
  MutableSub with properties:
    Prop: 1

>> i = ImmutableSub(10)
i = 
  ImmutableSub with properties:
    Prop: 10

>> i.Prop = 1;
Error using Super/set.Prop
Prop is immutable
```